# Getting Information from Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

How to get free apps details **(App name,Description,App icon,Rating)** from google play using php api in android.

i found one example [this link](https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API#topFreeApps),but i got error on `include_once('api/playStoreApi.php');`
and `$class_init = new PlayStoreApi;`. Please help regarding this

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: The include path is wrong,
this should be include_once('core/playStoreApi.php');